# Prevent comment formatting in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am doing inline documentation on an API, using XML in comments, and I'd like to keep the indenting. Every time the document is formatted (CTRL+K CTRL+D), all indenting inside /* */ is removed. Is there an option to prevent this from happening? It looks like I can keep the indenting if I use single line commenting, but I'd rather not resort to this. Thanks for your time.

```
/*
<ObjectProperty Name="id" Type="string" DefaultValue="''">
<Description>
Unique identifier of the data store. Primarily used for getting a handle  <docref class="ObjectManager">ObjectManager</docref>.
</Description>
<Examples>
<Example>
// Create an anonymous DataStore
// Update and Sort the data by using ObjectManager
new DataStore({ id: 'PersonsDS' });
ObjectManager.GetDataStore('PersonsDS').UpdateData([
{
ID: 1,
FirstName: 'Joe',
LastName: 'Bloggs'
},
{
ID: 2,
FirstName: 'Jane',
LastName: 'Doe'
}
]).Sort('LastName', 'desc');
</Example>
</Examples>
</ObjectProperty>
*/
```

Should look like

```
/*
<ObjectProperty Name="id" Type="string" DefaultValue="''">
    <Description>
        Unique identifier of the data store. Primarily used for getting a handle  <docref class="ObjectManager">ObjectManager</docref>.
    </Description>
    <Examples>
        <Example>
            // Create an anonymous DataStore
            // Update and Sort the data by using ObjectManager
            new DataStore({ id: 'PersonsDS' });
            ObjectManager.GetDataStore('PersonsDS').UpdateData([
            {
                ID: 1,
                FirstName: 'Joe',
                LastName: 'Bloggs'
            },
            {
                ID: 2,
                FirstName: 'Jane',
                LastName: 'Doe'
            }
            ]).Sort('LastName', 'desc');
        </Example>
    </Examples>
</ObjectProperty>
*/
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @Dave You are pasting the second code block into VS2010; formatting the doc; and you are not losing the indenting? That would give me hope that it IS possible.

Comment: Yes, I took your second (formatted) code block, pasted it into my editor, hit CTRL-K, CTRL-D, and it reformatted all of the code on the page, but left your comments intact.

Comment: @Dave. When you say "my editor", are you using VS2010? Any option changes that come to mind that would affect this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: yes, I'm using VS2010.  I'm using the default settings for the editor, however I also have the Productivity Power Tools extension loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 with [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) installed (free extension from Microsoft, a must-have) this problem does not exist - formatting is preserved in comments when the file is automatically formatted via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.